# Dynamically adding a new option value to a selectbox if it isn't already in there

Tags: javascript

I have a small bit of a delema.

I have the following static select box below, however, the database will compare its cell value to that of the select box and select it.

My question to you is how can I design a function that would dynamically add a new select option (at the end of the existing list) if it already isn't in the list?

This doesn't seem to be working for me?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function test() {
                //document.getElementById('name').innerHTML = "test"
                document.getElementById('name').text = "test"
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <select id="name">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="John">John</option>
            <option value="Patrick">Patrick</option>
            <option value="Jean">Jean</option>
            <option value="Jackie">Jackie</option>
            <option value="Stephanie">Stephanie</option>
            <option value="Nicole">Nicole</option>
            <option value="Lucie">Lucie</option>
        </select>
        <input id="btn1" type="button" value="testme" onclick="test()" />
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: I dont know what you are trying to do, but check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TqpUa/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a function which loops through all the options in the select element and if the option value doesn't already exist, append it to the select tag.

```
var addOption = function(value){
    var select = document.getElementById('name'),        // get the select tag
        options = select.getElementsByTagName('option'), // get all option tags within that select
        alreadyExists = false;
    for(var i = 0, l = options.length; i < l; i++){      // loop through the existing options
        if(options[i].value == value)                    // check if value already exists
            alreadyExists = true;
    }
    if(!alreadyExists){                                  // if value doesn't already exist
        var newOption = document.createElement('option');// create a new option and add it to the select
        newOption.value = value;
        newOption.innerHTML = value;
        select.appendChild(newOption); 
    }
};
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/2TZ45/

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to check each one:

```
function test() {

   var checkWhat = 'test'; // value to check for 

   var options = document.getElementById('name').getElementsByTagName('option'),
       exists  = false;

   for (var i=options.length; i--;) {
        if ( options[i].value == checkWhat ) {
            exists = true; // an option with that value already exists
            break;
        }
   }

   if (!exists) { 
       var option = document.createElement('option');

       option.value = 'test';
       option.innerHTML = 'test';

       document.getElementById('name').appendChild(option);
   }

}
```